# How to assign same value to a new variable by group condition on another variable?

Tags: r

I have tried many times to solve the problem in the title. Here is the code I used, I hope someone can help. Thank you.

This is the dataframe in the beginning:

```
  df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
       Diagnosis=c("NEG","NEG","POS","NEG","NEG","NEG","NEG","POS","POS"))
```

I want to create a new variable "Diagnosis_approach" = 'a' for the group with the same ID if 'Diagnosis' ever equals to 1 and "Diagnosis_approach" = 'b' for the group with the same ID if 'Diagnosis'never equals to 1. This is the data frame I want to get:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
      Diagnosis=c("NEG","NEG","POS","NEG","NEG","NEG","NEG","POS","POS"),
      Diagnosis_approach=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a"))
```

I used the following code, but the results seem not correct. The value of 'Diagnosis' is supposed to be the same for the same ID, but this code did not get the intended results.

```
df<-df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Diagnosis_approach=case_when(Diagnosis %in%"POS"~"a",Diagnosis 
        %in% "NEG" ~ "b"))
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on the following statement? "I want to create a new variable "Diagnosis_approach" = 'a' for the group with the same ID if 'Diagnosis' ever equals to 1 and "Diagnosis_approach" = 'b' for the group with the same ID if 'Diagnosis'never equals to 1."

Comment: I meant "Diagnosis_approach" = 'a' if 'Diagnosis' = 1 for at least one time. e.g. for ID =1, Diagnosis=c("NEG","NEG","POS"), then Diagnosis_approach=c("a","a","a"). for ID=2, Diagnosis=c("NEG","NEG","NEG"), then Diagnosis_approach=c("b","b","b").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  df,
  Diagnosis_approach = c("b", "a")[1 + ave(Diagnosis == "POS", ID, FUN = any)]
)
```

gives

```
  ID Diagnosis Diagnosis_approach
1  1       NEG                  a
2  1       NEG                  a
3  1       POS                  a
4  2       NEG                  b
5  2       NEG                  b
6  2       NEG                  b
7  3       NEG                  a
8  3       POS                  a
9  3       POS                  a
```

---

If you want using `tidyverse`, try below

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Diagnosis_approach = case_when(
      "POS" %in% Diagnosis ~ "a",
      TRUE ~ "b"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a large database with around 10 million records. Is it possible to use the tidiverse functions as I attempted to do in the code? What was wrong is the code I tried? If I would use the base r solution, the "diagnosis" and "diagnosis_approace" in my real database both have more than two categories, does the code also work in such case?

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding can you explain the idea of this code: [1 + ave(Diagnosis == "POS", ID, FUN = any)]. it's not clear how it works? Thank you.

Comment: @Jie `ave` help you grouping in terms of variables. Here, in `ave(Diagnosis == "POS", ID, FUN = any)`, you group `Diagnosis == "POS"` in terms of `ID`, and you will apply function `any` within each group. Maybe this link will help you understand https://magesblog.com/post/2013-09-10-ave-and-function-in-r/

Comment: I can understand how AVE() work. And I understand you used transform() to create a new variable with specified values ("b","a"). What do mean by 1+AVE()?

Comment: @Jie `àve()` here returns logical values, i.e., `FALSE` or `TRUE`. If we apply `1 + FALSE`, the values will be coerced to numerical `1`. This works similar to `1 + TRUE`. Then you have indices for selecting from `c("b","a")`

Comment: A follow-up question out of curiosity, I am not farmilar use ave() before, but it seems ave() is a function to calculate means by groups. For code in your solution, is it more intuitive to use other subset functions like tapply(), which can also apply a specific function to all stratified groups? e.g. Diagnosis_approach = c("b", "a")[1 + tapply(Diagnosis == "POS", ID, FUN = any)]

Comment: @Jie `tapply` gives a compact summary in terms of groups, You'd better run `tapply` and see what it gives.